# How can I union a set of images?

Tags: image-processing, image, filtering

What is the best way to do image de-duplication in Mathematica. I've used a tool called [Visipics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page) in the past, which works well, but I need to do this in MMA.

Basically the function I'm looking for, call it `ImageUnion` would return only the images that are unique under some set of heuristics and thresholds. For instance:

```
lena1 = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
lena2 = ImageResize[lena1, {151, 116}];
Union[{lena1, lena2}]
```

should only return one image. So the algorithm for `ImageUnion` could first compare meta data like file-size and name, but this wouldn't be enough to rule out a match, so what next?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to consider this "too broad."  If someone has already implemented something and wants to post it let me know.  Likewise if this can be handled concisely in some way I failed to consider I'll be happy to reopen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Agreed. There are many questions/tools that I have or want to start a discussion about but they too general. I can't seem to find a place to ask them, Wolfram Community isn't well attended, are there any other places to start a discussion like this?

Comment: [Chat] can be productive if you are there at the right time.  I am not unsympathetic to this and I am sorry to see the old MathGroup disappear as it was a better forum for this kind of thing I believe.

Comment: I am not familiar with the climate over there but perhaps [DSP.SE] would at least help you focus on the right sort of algorithm to use, etc.  Try *their* chat as well.